# Material icon not rendering properly

Tags: angular, angular-material, google-material-icons

Material icon not rendering properly in my project, i installed properly but even though not showing in browser.

i followed below steps:

```
npm install material-design-icons
```

*.angular-cli.json*

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css"
      ],
```

*app.module.ts*

```
import {MatSidenavModule, MatToolbarModule, MatIconModule} from '@angular/material';
```

*app.component.html*

```
<mat-toolbar-row>
    <span>Second Line</span>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <mat-icon class="example-icon">verified_user</mat-icon>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
```

Comment: `mat-icon` -> `md-icon`, prior to the release yesterday it was the preferred route to import `MdIconModule` rather than `MatIconModule` as well.

Comment: Side note... did you make sure to include the actual fonts (and not just the css) http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web?

Answer (score 29):

I had the same issue. Caused because I was importing the material theme before the fonts in my theme.scss.

Should be:

```
@import url( 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700|Material+Icons');

@import '~@angular/material/theming';
```

Answer (score 7):

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">`

make sure this has been added to your index.html.

Answer (score 5):

I had made my own text font `!important`

had to make the icons more important:

```
.lato * {
  font-family: 'Lato' !important;
}

.mat-icon{
  font-family: 'Material Icons' !important;
}
```

Comment: Worked for me. `.material-icon` if you're using past today.

Comment: Strangely for me just icons with underscore were not working, but this fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, because I forgot to add the module on NgModule.imports :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatIconModule
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

consider using google CDN instead by adding the following to your `index.html`:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Edit:**

move/download the CSS file and place it in your assets folder and then in your `angular-cli.json` you add the following to your styles array:

```
"../src/assets/material-icons.css"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this in Angular 6, solution ended up being adding mat-icon-button,

```
<button mat-icon-button type="button" 
    (click)="yourMethod()">
    <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Make sure you add MatIconModule to your app.module.ts imports and it should work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Check your console for miscellaneous errors.

If you have a miscellaneous error in your component it could be preventing your `mat-icon` from initializing properly and you'll just see the textual representation of the glyph instead.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue, instead of icon "close" text was coming for me.
It was internet issue , internet was slow so maticon module was not loaded properly.
Reconnecting with good network strength solved my issue.